# Scroll change data in UITableView objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a uitableView that in each row I have 4 button and name of all buttions is "W",

when I run the program: I have just "W" for my first 4 button in First row

and when I scroll my table I will get more button name "W"

Does any one know what is the problem?

Thanks in advance

my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

int column = 4;
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {

    // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.5+83*i,10, 80,115)];
    myButton.tag=(column*indexPath.row)+i;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    UILabel *btnTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 10, 30, 10)];
    [btnTitle setText:@"W"];
    [btnTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [myButton addSubview:btnTitle];

           }
return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you manage to dequeue a cell, why are you creating all the buttons again?

Comment: Could you revise your question. I'm not sure what your asking or what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Abizem said. "The cell will have many many buttons... AND btnTitles" He is right.

Your code will invoke "out of memory" and "Slow" while scroll table view.

Create a CustomTableViewCell class.

---

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    NSArray *_buttons;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button1, button2, button3, button4;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *buttons;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell
...
@dynamic buttons;
- (NSArray*)buttons
{
   if (_buttons == nil) {
       _buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4, nil];
   }
   return _buttons; // I fixed it _button --> _buttons
}
@end
```

---

- Create a empty xib file.
- Drag and drop a UITableViewCell.
- And Drag and drop 4 UIButtons on the UITableViewCell.
- Select and change UITableViewCell custom class to CustomTableViewCell.
- Link button1, button2, button3, button4 to xibs item.

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
int column = 4;
for (int i=0; i<column; i++) {
    // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    UIButton *myButton = [cell.buttons objectAtIndex:i];
    //myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.5+83*i,10, 80,115); You can design on interface builder
    myButton.tag=(column*indexPath.row)+i;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //myButton.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(25, 10, 30, 10); You can design on interface builder
    [myButton.textLabel. setText:@"W"];
    [myButton.textLabel. setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 }
return cell;
}
```

---

- Sorry. not "ni" --> "nil"
- return _button --> return _buttons

---

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    NSArray *_buttons;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button1, button2, button3, button4;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *buttons; // <----- Check it.
@end
```

Comment: I used storyboard not xib then what should I do?

Comment: then in the end I have 52 buttons should I create all 52 buttons? property (...) IBOutlet UIButton *button1, button2, button3, button4;

Comment: Add 4 button only per a cell.

Comment: hmm I will add detailed description.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray *buttons; // <----- Check it.

Answer (score 1):

**I can't comment on answers, therefore I changed this answer**
boiljong's solution is the right one. As booiljoung's post, you can easily use it in storyboard. First you should customize the UITableViewCell in storyboard. The first row of UITableView is a UITableViewCell (If you haven't delete it when you add the UITableView to your storyboard). Then add 4 buttons to it and set its class to CustomUITableViewCell. Link the buttons to your CustomUITableViewCell. The **most important thing** is don't forget to change the **Identifier** to the one you used in your code tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Please see the screenshot I uploaded. And your errors in your code are caused by typo ni should be ni**l** and _button should be **_buttons**
[image: Custom UITableViewCell in storyboard]

**Old answers**
The creation of buttons needs to be done only when the cell is nil, if the cell is not nil, it means tableview is **reusing** the "old" cells you created with buttons. When calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, it always **reuses** the cells if possible. For example, use the cells those are not in current screen. They already have 4 buttons named "W". Therefore, each time a newly coming in cell will have 4 buttons more when you are scrolling. You can move the buttons creation code into the code bracket if ( cell == nil ) {...}

But it is hard to manipulate the buttons' titles when scrolling to new rows. It is better to customize the UITableViewCell with your own. You can find the reference from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have written the Button out of below pasted code

`if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}`

You can copy that line of code after and paste it after below line of code

`cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

and one more think you are creating the text label separately even though you can give the button title
as

`[myButton setTitle:@"Somethig" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

by this you will save memory too